# Showing that if the restriction of $f$ to closed subspaces is continuous, then $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, metric-spaces, continuity

$X$ is a space equal to $A\bigcup B$, where A and B are subspaces of X. Define $F:X\rightarrow Y$. Let the restricted functions $F|A:A\rightarrow Y$ and $F|B:B\rightarrow Y$ be continuous. I want to show that, if A and B are closed in X, then F is continuous.

What I have:

$F$ is continuous in $A$, so $\exists \delta , U(a\in A, \delta)$ has a corresponding epsilon ball $U(y\in Y, \epsilon)$, and same for B. I also know that $X=A\bigcup B$, so that $F(A\bigcup B)=F(X)$. I want to claim here then that $F(X) = F(A)\bigcup F(B)$, and any delta ball in X has a corresponding epsilon ball in F(X). However, I don't know if this is right, or how to make the proof strong, especially since I don't know how A and B being closed in X affects the result

Comment: When you say "space" and "subspace" do you mean these have the property of linear spaces, so linear combinations of vectors in these spaces are also in these spaces?  Also, if so, is it possible for $A, B, A \cup B$ to all be (closed) spaces without having either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$?

Comment: PS:  I do not understand the notation in the first line of "What I have," particularly what $U(a \in A, \delta)$ means.

Comment: For the first question, I believe so, since X is a metric space. Not sure about the second. The notation was a bit clumsy, but it was basically expressing "the delta ball around a, for given a in A"

Comment: So you meant $\cup_{a \in A} B_{\delta}(a)$, where $B_{\delta}(a)$ is the [open/closed?] $\delta$-ball around $a$?

Comment: In any case, do you agree that if you can show either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$, then you are done?

Comment: That would satisfy the problem, but I'm not sure how true that is or how to prove it. Is that a consequence of A and B being closed in X?

Comment: Perhaps you can try finding an example for it to _not_ be true, which then may give insight.

Comment: Okay. I know that $A$ being closed in $X$ means that $A^C$ is open. If there is some boundary elements of B not in A, then $A^C$ is closed, so then A must contain B completely. The reverse is also true, so in fact A = B. Is that logic sound, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: I agree that all boundary elements of $B$ are also in $A$.  I did not follow your reasoning after that, and the conclusion $A=B$ is not correct since we might have $A$ is a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $B=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46103/discussion-between-george-and-michael).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those instances where general topology makes things both more general and easier. In fact the result is true when $X$ is a mere topological space, and $A$ and $B$ are subspaces in the topological sense.

**Topological Proof:**

> To prove $f$ continuous we must prove that for any $C$ closed in $Y$, $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$. Now
>   $$f^{-1}(C)=(f^{-1}(C)\cap A)\cup(f^{-1}(C)\cap B)$$
>   and by hypothesis both sets are closed in the subspace topology. This means that
>   $$f^{-1}(C)\cap A=A\cap K$$
>   $$f^{-1}(C)\cap B= B\cap H$$
>   where $K,H$ are closed in $X$. But this means that $f^{-1}(C)\cap A$ and $f^{-1}(C)\cap B$ are both closed, being the intersection of two closed sets. Therefore $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed being the union of two closed sets.

NOTE: The same result remains true if $A$ and $B$ are both *open*. The exact same proof works, just proving that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for any $U\subset Y$ open.

A counterexample with $A$ and $B$ not both open or closed is $f(x)=\chi_{[0,+\infty)}(x) $ and $A=(-\infty,0)$, $B=[0,+\infty)$, with the Euclidean topology.

**A more *metric-space flavoured* proof**:

> Fix any $x\in A$. By hypothesis for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta(\epsilon,A)$ such that for every $y\in A$
>    $$d(x,y)<\delta(\epsilon, A)\implies d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon.$$
>   If $x\in B$ the same is true for another $\delta(\epsilon, B)$ and $y\in B$. Then setting $\delta(\epsilon)=\min\{\delta(\epsilon, A),\delta(\epsilon, B)\}$, for every $y\in X$ we have
>   $$d(x,y)<\delta(\epsilon)\implies d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$$
>   and this is true for every $\epsilon>0$, thus $f$ is continuous at $x$.
>
> If instead $x\not\in B$, the ball $B(x,\delta)$ is not contained in $B$ for $\delta\leq \delta_x$, with $\delta_x$ small enough, since $B$ is closed. Thus for $\delta\leq \delta_x$ we have $B(x,\delta)\cap A= B(x,\delta)$ and setting $\delta(\epsilon)=\min\{\delta_x,\delta(x,A)\}$, for every $y\in X$ again the implication 
>   $$d(x,y)<\delta(\epsilon)\implies d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$$
>   holds.

Comment: This does not seem to be easier or more general, since the result can easily be proved even without the closed assumption just using basic properties of a vector space (with no topology concepts required). [see my answer]

Comment: I see you are removing the vector space assumption...In that case the "continuity" portion of the problem makes more sense.  (Else, the more general statement that either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$ immediately proves it).  This relates to my very first comment about the meaning of the word "space." I suspect that this question should not have had the "linear algebra" tag.

Comment: @Michael I agree that the linear algebra tag is misleading. In the vector spaces case you are right and the best solution is the one you have proposed. However it is more a matter of proving $X= A\cup B\implies A\subset B\lor B\subset A$ than a matter of continuity, and that's why I assumed he was talking about a metric space (in addition to the "metric spaces" tag of course...)

Comment: @Del If you wanted to prove continuity in one single point of $A\cap B$, could you remove the hypothesis of $A$ and $B$ being both closed or both open?

Comment: @416333 Yes. In fact, continuity holds in the whole intersection. It is maybe simpler from the metric point of view: for every $x\in A$, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta_x^A$ such that for every $z\in A$ such that $d(x,z)<\delta_x^A$ it holds $d(f(x),f(z))<\epsilon$. Similarly there is a $\delta_x^B$ for every $x\in B$. Then for every $x\in A\cap B$ we can take $\delta_x=\min\{\delta_x^A,\delta_x^B\}$. A similar argument in fact holds in the topological setting, working with neighbourhoods and using the fact that the intersection of two neighbourhoods is still a neighbourhood.

Comment: @Del I'm trying to prove it: because $f\restriction A$ is continuous, then for every $p\in A$ and every open set $V$ in $Y$ such that $f(p)\in V$, there exists a open set $U_A$ in $A$ such that $p\in U$ and $f(U)\subset V$. The same for $B$, there exists a open set $U_B$ of $B$ such that $p\in U_B$ and $f(U_B)\subset V$. But these are NOT open sets in $X$, and with the subspace topology, I can't assure that $U_A\cap U_B$ will be open in $X$.

Comment: @416333 By definition of subspace topology $U_A=A\cap W_A$, with $W_A$ open in $X$, and similarly $U_B=B\cap W_B$, $W_B$ open. Then $W_A\cap W_B$ is open and $W_A\cap W_B=(W_A\cap W_B)\cap (A\cup B)=(W_A\cap W_B\cap A)\cup (W_A\cap W_B\cap B)=(W_B\cap U_A)\cup (W_A\cup U_B)\subseteq U_A\cup U_B$ therefore $f(W_A\cap W_B)\subseteq f(U_A\cup U_B)\subseteq V$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a vector space over any field.  Suppose $X = A \cup B$ where $A$ and $B$ are both subspaces.

Claim: Either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$.

Proof:  Suppose not. Then we can find a point $a \in A \cap B^c$ and another point $b \in B \cap A^c$.  Then $(a+b)$ is a linear combination of points in the vector space $A \cup B$, and so $(a+b) \in A \cup B$.

Case 1:  Suppose $(a+b) \in A$.  Then $a \in A$ and $(a+b) \in A$ and so every linear combination of $a$ and $(a+b)$ is also in $A$. We can reach a simple contradiction.

Case 2: Suppose $(a +b) \notin A$.  Then $(a+b) \in B$ and we reach a similar contradiction. $\Box$

Comment: Recall that every field contains elements "$1$" and "$-1$".